# Edit text real data missing when scrolling in a recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recycler view of edit texts, however when scrolling my data of edit texts sometimes disappear and sometimes repeat itself in other edit texts.

I also use two functions in my adapter to get the values passed for edit texts in my case (product & price) but as I said I don't get the right values so I'm looking for your help guys.

This is my recycler view adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(var myList: List<ProductModelClass>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemToAddBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {}


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = ItemToAddBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        holder.binding.etProductName.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                val text: String = s.toString()
                myList[position].product = text
            }

        })





        holder.binding.etPrice.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                val text: String = s.toString()
                myList[position].price = text
            }

        })
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }


    fun getProduct(): ArrayList<String>{
        val productList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        for(element in myList) {
            productList.add(element.product)
        }
        return productList
    }


    fun getPrice(): ArrayList<String>{
        val priceList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        for(element in myList) {
            priceList.add(element.price)
        }
        return priceList
    }


}
```

Comment: A recyclerView reused the view already on the screen and only updates what needs to be updated. So what you need is a ViewModel that saves all these text data and `onBind` set these data to `<EditText>.text`.

Comment: @clmno thanks for ur answer, but I already have a modelClass called ProductModelClass. please if u can write the code i will appreciate it although if it wrote by java